# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/110826232119603-1.jpg (Permission denied)

Tags: android, bitmap

Getting crash when trying to upload photo from gallery.
And not all the images causes crash but few else all the photos get upload successfully with Camera as well as Gallery. But unable to understand why some images cause crash.

ERROR LOG

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/110826232119603-1.jpg 
(Permission denied)
03-24 20:47:15.898 21129-21129/com.shareyourconnectionsyc 
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result 
ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/488 flg=0x1 }} to activity com.shareyourconnectionsyc/com.shareyourconnectionsyc.ui.activity.EditProfileImageActivity}: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4226)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4269)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1597)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6320)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1085)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:946)
Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
at com.shareyourconnectionsyc.ui.activity.EditProfileImageActivity.compressImage(EditProfileImageActivity.java:715)
at com.shareyourconnectionsyc.ui.activity.EditProfileImageActivity.onActivityResult(EditProfileImageActivity.java:387)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6919)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4222)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4269) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1597) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6320) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1085) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:946)
```

Here is the Acitivty

```
public class EditProfileImageActivity extends ParentActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.syc_editProfilePic:

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_image_layout, null);
            dialog.setContentView(view1);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog.show();

            galleryLayout = view1.findViewById(R.id.gallery_layout);
            cameraLayout = view1.findViewById(R.id.camera_layout);

            galleryLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    dialog.dismiss();

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                        if (checkPermission()) {
                            selectfromGallery();
                            // Code for above or equal 23 API Oriented Device
                            // Your Permission granted already .Do next code
                        } else {
                            requestPermission(); // Code for permission
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (isKitKat) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                            intent.setType("image/*");
                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            cameraLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, CameraActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent1, 2);
                }
            });
            break;

        case R.id.finishImage:
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_top);
            break;
    }
}

private void selectfromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        s = data.getStringExtra("result");
        Log.e("newImagePathEDIT", s);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);            // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        // String s = String.valueOf(fileUri);
        // options.inSampleSize = 8;
        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(s, options);
        //profileImageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        if (bgImage.equals("editbacghroundImage")) {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                new TaskChangeProfileBackgroundImage().execute();
            } else {
                SignUpDialog dialog = new SignUpDialog(context, "No Internet Connection", "Sorry, no Internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and try again.");
                dialog.show();
            }
        } else {
            if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                new TaskUpdateProfileImage().execute();
            } else {
                SignUpDialog dialog = new SignUpDialog(context, "No Internet Connection", "Sorry, no Internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and try again.");
                dialog.show();
            }
        }
    } else if (data != null && data.getData() != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        boolean isImageFromGoogleDrive = false;
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

            if ("com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                String[] split = docId.split(":");
                String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    strImagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                    compressImage(strImagePath);
                } else {
                    Pattern DIR_SEPORATOR = Pattern.compile("/");
                    Set<String> rv = new HashSet<>();
                    String rawExternalStorage = System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
                    String rawSecondaryStoragesStr = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
                    String rawEmulatedStorageTarget = System.getenv("EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET");
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rawEmulatedStorageTarget)) {
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rawExternalStorage)) {
                            rv.add("/storage/sdcard0");
                        } else {
                            rv.add(rawExternalStorage);
                        }
                    } else {
                        String rawUserId;
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                            rawUserId = "";
                        } else {
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                            String[] folders = DIR_SEPORATOR.split(path);
                            String lastFolder = folders[folders.length - 1];
                            boolean isDigit = false;
                            try {
                                Integer.valueOf(lastFolder);
                                isDigit = true;
                            } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
                            }
                            rawUserId = isDigit ? lastFolder : "";
                        }
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(rawUserId)) {
                            rv.add(rawEmulatedStorageTarget);
                        } else {
                            rv.add(rawEmulatedStorageTarget + File.separator + rawUserId);
                        }
                    }
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(rawSecondaryStoragesStr)) {
                        String[] rawSecondaryStorages = rawSecondaryStoragesStr.split(File.pathSeparator);
                        Collections.addAll(rv, rawSecondaryStorages);
                    }
                    String[] temp = rv.toArray(new String[rv.size()]);

                    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                        File tempf = new File(temp[i] + "/" + split[1]);
                        if (tempf.exists()) {
                            strImagePath = temp[i] + "/" + split[1];
                            compressImage(strImagePath);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if ("com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

                Cursor cursor = null;
                String column = "_data";
                String[] projection = {
                        column
                };

                try {
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null,
                            null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                        strImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                        compressImage(strImagePath);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                }
            } else if ("com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                String[] split = docId.split(":");
                String type = split[0];

                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }

                String selection = "_id=?";
                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };

                Cursor cursor = null;
                String column = "_data";
                String[] projection = {
                        column
                };

                try {
                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                            null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                        strImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                        compressImage(strImagePath);
                    }
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null)
                        cursor.close();
                }
            } else if ("com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                isImageFromGoogleDrive = true;
            }
        } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            Cursor cursor = null;
            String column = "_data";
            String[] projection = {
                    column
            };

            try {
                cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null,
                        null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    strImagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                    compressImage(strImagePath);
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
        } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            strImagePath = uri.getPath();
            compressImage(strImagePath);
        }


        if (isImageFromGoogleDrive) {
            try {
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            launchUploadActivity(true);
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void launchUploadActivity(boolean b) {

    s = uriSting;
    Log.e("newImagePath", s);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);            // bimatp factory
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    if (bgImage.equals("editbacghroundImage")) {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new TaskChangeProfileBackgroundImage().execute();
        } else {
            SignUpDialog dialog = new SignUpDialog(context, "No Internet Connection", "Sorry, no Internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and try again.");
            dialog.show();
        }
    } else {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            new TaskUpdateProfileImage().execute();
        } else {
            SignUpDialog dialog = new SignUpDialog(context, "No Internet Connection", "Sorry, no Internet connectivity detected. Please reconnect and try again.");
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}

private void compressImage(String imageUri) {
    String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//      by setting this field as true, the actual bitmap pixels are not loaded in the memory. Just the bounds are loaded. If
//      you try the use the bitmap here, you will get null.
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

    //imageView_one.setImageBitmap(bmp);
//        storeCameraPhotoInSDCard(bmp);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
//      max Height and width values of the compressed image is taken as 816x612

    float maxHeight = 800.0f;//1500.0f;
    float maxWidth = 600.0f;//1200.0f;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    Log.e("actualHeight", String.valueOf(actualHeight));
    Log.e("actualWidth", String.valueOf(actualWidth));
    Log.e("imgRatio", String.valueOf(imgRatio));
    Log.e("maxRatio", String.valueOf(maxRatio));

//      width and height values are set maintaining the aspect ratio of the image

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        }
    }
//      setting inSampleSize value allows to load a scaled down version of the original image
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);

//      inJustDecodeBounds set to false to load the actual bitmap
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

//      this options allow android to claim the bitmap memory if it runs low on memory
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];

    try {
//          load the bitmap from its path
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Log.e("scaledImage", String.valueOf(scaledBitmap.getByteCount()));
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    assert scaledBitmap != null;
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));

//      check the rotation of the image and display it properly
    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0,
                scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix,
                true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    String filename = getFilename();
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
//          write the compressed bitmap at the destination specified by filename.
        scaledBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);
        Log.e("final  image", String.valueOf(scaledBitmap.getByteCount()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String getFilename() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "MyImage");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
        String newpath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        // Toast.makeText(context,newpath,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    uriSting = (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    return uriSting;
}

private String getRealPathFromURI(String contentURI) {
    Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(contentURI);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
}

private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }
    final float totalPixels = width * height;
    final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;
    while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
        inSampleSize++;
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}

 private void requestPermission() {
    try {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                // Explain to the user_plachoder why we need to write the permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "This app need the permission of Camera.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unable to understand why few images causes crash.
Please help.

Comment: `ArithmeticException: divide by zero`.

Comment: also at this line `if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)` you need to make sure 2nd permission was granted because after this check you determine to pick image from gallery which the image can be from external storage... in your code the first permission is WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE, second permission  is READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: `crash when trying to upload photo from gallery`. There is no code that tries to upload a file. For the rest you dumped a bunch of irrelevant code. Please remove all irrelevant stuff.

Comment: Updated one function which uploads the photo.

Comment: simple ur calculation was wrong or u can say that ur dividing by zero
    `float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;`
   `float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;`

Comment: Yes, but same code is working for most cases, so why not for few?
Why is this error coming for few?

Comment: `EditProfileImageActivity.java:715` - Which line this is?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `options.outHeight` and `options.outWidth` are returned as 0
try this

Change `Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);` to

```
try {
InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                   Uri.parse(path));
bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Did, but got same error.
Yes, the height and width are 0 that's why it's getting crashed.

Comment: Did, but got same error.
Yes, the height and width are 0 that's why it's getting crashed. But this happens only for few cases i.e. photos.
Please check first line of error "Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/110826232119603-1.jpg 
(Permission denied)", did it has to do anything with this specific image which is from cache?

Comment: in requestpermission method are you checking for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, if no you will have to

Comment: Yes, permission is granted.

Comment: share code for `checkPermission()` and `requestPermission()`

Comment: private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

Comment: added requestPermission() above

Answer (score 0):

Try to get path like this:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    public String getPath(final Uri uri) {

        final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(activity, uri)) {
            //Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
            if (com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority()) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            }
            // DownloadsProvider
            else if ("com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(activity, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            // MediaProvider
            else if ("com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority())) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                        split[1]
                };
                return getDataColumn(activity, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
            else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                //Goole photos uri
                if ("com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority())
                    return uri.getLastPathSegment();

                //Goole doc uri
                else if ("com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority()))
                    return uri.getLastPathSegment();

                return getRealPathFromURI(uri);
            } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And `getDataColumn` is:

```
private String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection,
                                 String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = {
                column
        };
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs,
                    null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            } else {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

And `getRealPathFromURI` is:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
        String result;
        Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null,
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor == null) {
            result = contentURI.getPath();
        } else {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            try {
                int idx = cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
                result = cursor.getString(idx);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AndyUtils
                        .showToast(
                                activity.getString(R.string.text_image_select_fail),
                                activity);
                result = "";
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Try to print log of path you are getting with this method? What path did you get?

Comment: For working cases the path is "/storage/emulated/0/MyImage/1521961671640.jpg" and for non working cases the path is "/data/user/0/com.android.providers.downloads/cache/110826232119603-1.jpg"

Comment: It seems, the images it picks from cache (i don't know how) causes issue.

Comment: Call `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` on the Intent that you use with `startActivity()` and the FileProvider Uri. Without that, the activity has no rights to access your content.

Comment: Did but not working, there are some permission issue but i've already granted whichever required.

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly mentioned in the Log file that "Permission Denied", declare permission in manifest file and then try again. Hope this will solve your problem.